# Magento 2 : Assign product to multiple category using sql query programmatically

Tags: magento2, category

Is there any way that I can assign **products to category** using SQL in code?
Currently, Category Result Sets are too large, the request gets heavy, so unable to save a Category the traditional way.

Answer (score 2):

**Category and Products** are mapped on `catalog_category_product` table.

Where there are 4 columns: `entity_id, category_id, product_id, position`.

Where `entity_id` is the *auto-increment column* .

So you can run this by Sql:

```
    INSERT INTO `catalog_category_product`(`category_id`, `product_id`) 
    VALUES ('category_id','product_id');
```

You can use it by simple corePHP program like:

1. Create A `temporary` table on your database having 4 columns `('id', 'category_id', 'product_id', 'flag')` and stored data.
2. Create a PHP file on root, and Connect to database.
3. `SELECT` from this temporary table and `INSERT` into `catalog_category_product` table and if update success update flag.

Comment: Hello, how to use it in program ?

Comment: I hope Now you better Understand it.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can also assign products to category programmatically by using CategoryLinkManagementInterface By this way.

```
  * @var CategoryLinkManagementInterface
  */
 protected $categoryLinkManagement;
 public function __construct(
     \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryLinkManagementInterface $categoryLinkManagementInterface
 ) {
     $this->categoryLinkManagement = $categoryLinkManagementInterface;
   }
public function execute()
 {
 $this->categoryLinkManagement->assignProductToCategories(
                 $Productsku,
                 $categoryIds
             );
 }
```

By Using object Manager

```
categoryLinkManagement = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->get('Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryLinkManagementInterface');
categoryLinkManagement->assignProductToCategories(
                $product->getSku(),
                $product->getCategoryIds()
            );
```

Comment: When there are more then 1000+ products to execute with this function it gets 504 not found error